# Google Chrome extension that highlights all links on a webpage

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Is there a Google Chrome extension that highlights all links on a webpage like when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>?

Comment: You can try this one : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/website-links-checker/lhghoodlnemlhdiefakhjnegandfbamm

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a new bookmark in Chrome's bookmarks bar and set its address to the following JavaScript code:

> `javascript:(function(){for(i=0;i<document.links.length;i++)document.links[i].style.backgroundColor='#ffff00';})();`

(instead of `http://example.org`)

When you click that *bookmarklet*, all links on the page will get yellow background color. No need for an extension.

[image]